# pandas groupby().std() returns a different value from np.std

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, std

I have the following problem with `pandas.groupby()`: I have a dataset which can be divided into groups, but when I compute the standard deviation I get different results depending on whether I use `groupby()` or if I split the groups by hand.

Here is a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data': np.append(np.random.normal(1,1,10),np.random.normal(-1,1,10)),
    'type': np.append(np.ones(10), 2*np.ones(10))
})
```

(Below I pasted the actual values if you want to reproduce exactly.)

This is what I get using `groupby()`:

```
df.groupby('type').std()
    data
type    
1.0 0.670406
2.0 1.235369
```

and here is what I get computing the standard deviation for `type==1` by hand:

```
np.std(df[ df.type==1 ].data)
0.6360030713759871
```

I really don't know what is going on, can anyone please explain?
Why do I get `0.670` in the first case and `0.636` in the second?
I can't understand how these values can be different, as `groupby().std()` is supposed to run `numpy.std()` in the background, right?

---

```
df.values
array([[ 2.1472923 ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.92915175,  1.        ],
       [ 2.94089156,  1.        ],
       [ 1.88584446,  1.        ],
       [ 0.69798067,  1.        ],
       [ 1.56013451,  1.        ],
       [ 2.83390388,  1.        ],
       [ 1.57214222,  1.        ],
       [ 1.41883281,  1.        ],
       [ 1.50841901,  1.        ],
       [-1.43944992,  2.        ],
       [-0.57068851,  2.        ],
       [-1.67287795,  2.        ],
       [-2.14790187,  2.        ],
       [-0.01767844,  2.        ],
       [-1.11745803,  2.        ],
       [-2.25692655,  2.        ],
       [ 0.38472557,  2.        ],
       [-0.57914187,  2.        ],
       [ 1.73321436,  2.        ]])
```

Comment: it's because of difference in the "delta degrees of freedom" argument between implementations (pandas uses 1 by default, numpy uses 0)) , use `np.std(..., ddof=1)` for example to check

Comment: @ChrisA thanks, doing as you suggest actually makes the values match :)
Just out of curiosity, why would the two use a different offset?